# Non-Platonic optimal hexadecahedron

Tags: geometry

Find coordinates of 16 points on a surface of unit sphere so that sum of distances to any point and its immediate neighbors is minimum.

Comment: What do you mean by immediate neighbours? The usual formulation of the problem of placing $n$ points on a sphere so that they are as "evenly spaced" as possible is to place them so that the minimum distance between any two of them is maximised. It is not solved in general. For more information and the generally accepted solution for 16 points see http://web.archive.org/web/20130511051512/http://www2.research.att.com/~njas/packings/

Comment: Thanks. Are there some other sources?